# How to find out how many times each process(or data) traversed using array

Tags: loops, traversal

Let there are 4 processes (20,30,40,50). I want to decrement 3 from each process when it is traversed first time, decrement 6 if it is traversed second time and remaining value when traversed third time. 
constraint: *any process can be picked up randomly (ie not in a sequential manner).

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what didn't work out the way you wanted to?

Comment: It's an Independent question. You may consider it as one single program to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through I'm little late, but you can try a hack.
For this what you'll need is either use mapping or a counter for each element of array.

Answer (score 1):

you can use simple map as a counter to store the number of time an element of array is traversed and with simple if condition based on counter you can decrement the value of the element accordingly.